# why is the ball not in the center of the window?

Tags: processing

The code:

```java
class Attractor {

  PVector location;
  float mass;

  Attractor() {
    location = new PVector(width/2, height/2);
    mass = 5;
  }

  void display() {
    stroke(0);
    fill(125);
    ellipse(location.x, location.y, mass*10, mass*10);
  }
}

Attractor a = new Attractor();

void setup()
{
  size(640, 360);
}

void draw()
{
  background(255);
  a.display();
}
```

The location of the ball is in Attractor object, that is, PVector(width/2, height/2).

So I wonder why when I run the code, it's not in the center but on the right and up side of the window.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @Neal Processing. It's in the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you create your `Attractor` **before** the `setup()` function is called. The `width` and `height` haven't been set yet, so they're at the default of `100`.

To fix this, just make sure you  create your `Attractor` after you call the `size()` function:

```java
Attractor a;

void setup()
{
  size(640, 360);
  a = new Attractor();
}
```

Comment: Thank you it really helped. No wonder in the book I am reading they initialize the object inside the setup function.